# Detect if visual studio 2010 and 2013 re-distributables are present using wix burn

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wix, burn, prerequisites

I've created an installer which requires Visual Studio re-distributables 2010 and 2013. My installer has been created using Wix Burn Bootstrapper. I tried to add the re-distributables to my bundle.wxs using the following lines.

```
<Fragment>

    <util:FileSearch Id="MFC120_Version_x86"
                 Variable="MFC120_Version_x86" Path="[SystemFolder]mfc120.dll"
                 Result="version"/>

    <PackageGroup Id="redist_vc120">
      <ExePackage Id="vc120" Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
                  SourceFile="vcredist_x86.exe"
                  Name="redist\vc120\vcredist_x86.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
                  InstallCondition="(NOT MFC120_Version_x86 >= v12.0.21005.1) OR NOT MFC120_Version_x86"
                  Protocol="burn"
                  />

    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>

    <util:FileSearch Id="MFC100_Version_x86"
                 Variable="MFC100_Version_x86" Path="[SystemFolder]mfc100.dll"
                 Result="version"/>

    <PackageGroup Id="redist_vc100">
      <ExePackage Id="vc100" Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
                  SourceFile="vcredist_x86.exe"
                  Name="redist\vc100\vcredist_x86.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
                  InstallCondition="(NOT MFC100_Version_x86 >= v10.0.30319.1) OR NOT MFC100_Version_x86"
                  Protocol="burn"
                  />

    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="redist">
      <PackageGroupRef Id="redist_vc110"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="redist_vc120"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

But it doesn't properly detect them and installer terminates. When I go see the Programs and Features, there are no installed packages. What am I doing wrong here? How to properly detect the presence of these and install them? I don't want to use the merge element method as I want to do this with my Bundle.wxs itself without creating a separate WIX project for these re-distributables. Please advice.

Comment: Those packages have their own logic that tells them what to do. I would just let them do it.

Comment: unfortunately it fails when there is a newer version of the same redistributable. How can I ignore this redistributable failure? because of this while installation is failing

Comment: Check the exit code and add appropriate ExitCode elements. Usually, only a couple can be/need be treated as non-errors. In particular, for 3010, you should let burn know a reboot is needed  Of course, installers _should_ be documented [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_8), particularly ones from Microsoft intended as redistributables and used in bootstrappers.